# Do customer community/customer community plus licenses have access to Data Loader/Data Import Wizard?

Tags: data-loader, customer-community, bulkification, userlicense

I want to know if customer community or customer community + user licenses have access to data transfer applications like Data loader or Data Import Wizard? If not, is APEX driving custom component the only solution to bulk data transfer?

Comment: I think it will work if the user is API Enabled.

Comment: @rahulgawale Thanks. This solution is available for partner community
A recent release by salesforce has exclusively mentioned that data loader will be available for Partner community licenses
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333681&type=1&mode=1
I just wanted to make sure if salesforce has made any similar releases for cc or cc+ licenses as well